# third order non linear differential equation initial values

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, nonlinear-analysis

I am having trouble solving the following problem:

I have to prove that for the equation $y'''+ (y-5)^2=0$ where $y(t_0)=5$, $y'(t_0)=0$ and $y''(t_0)=0$ where $t \in \Bbb R$, the problem has the unique solution $y(t)=5$. Any ideas for how it can be solved? I just started my MSc so I don't remember much in differential equations.

Comment: Hello and welcome to math.stackexchange! You should check that the given constant function is indeed a solution. Then the remaining task is to show that there can be no other solution. To do that, look for a theorem that gives conditions for uniqueness and existence of solutions of ordinary differential equations and apply it (i.e. check that all its assumptions are satisfied).

Comment: Thank you for answering! Would it be appropriate to try to estimate y' in order to use the Lipschitz theorem?

Comment: Rewrite the equation as a first order system and then show that the right hand side satisfies a local Lipschitz condition.

Comment: Now I got the right way to solve this thank you very much! :)